# What would be the best way of making this table?

Tags: php, html

So I want to create a table on my website that people can view but also add to.
But not delete

For example http://onii.pw/cn8u.png

Would be the start of the table and I would want people to add to it but not remove from it.

I was thinking a form submitting it with like 
Name : 
A checkbox for good/bad and then an input box for comments but I don't know what language I should do this in?

Thanks

Comment: There are many languages to do this, now php is the best especially for a beginner.

Comment: With PHP I would be able to be able to filter out good and bad and search for names (but I could just use control+F) I would be needing a MySQL table right? Because other people would be submitting to it? @Francesco

Comment: Yes, for this is necessary know MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php with HTML.
For example, this is your table:

```
<table class="my-table">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>GoodBad</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
</tr>
<?php
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['name'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['goodBad'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['comment'];?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

This is the form in order to insert new entries:

```
<form action="thispage.php" method="post">
Name: 
<input type="text" name="name"/>
Good/Bad: 
<select name="goodBad">
    <option value="good">Good</option>
    <option value="bad">Bad</option>
</select>
Comment:
<textarea name="comment"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

These are the queries in order to insert and fetch entries (place it at the start of the web page):

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbName = "database";
$user = "user";
$psw = "psw";

try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $psw);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection error";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $goodBad = $_POST['goodBad'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    //Insert SQL
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($name, $goodBad, $comment));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

//Select SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

And then your table on a MySQL Server:

```
CREATE DATABASE database;
USE database;
CREATE TABLE table
(
    name varchar(100),
    goodbad varchar(100),
    comment TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT pkTable PRIMARY KEY(name)
);
```

Don't forget to name the page `pagename.php` (pagename can be everything), and set the action of the form to the same page.

I hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much I will learn from this!

Comment: Hi. Upon trying this it will not submit it to the MySQL table. I did change the form action to the name of the page. Any issues you think could be doing this? I created the table and ran those queries.

Comment: I don't know. If you put your code here everybody can see it and help you